# Using basic authentication to consume NAV oData REST API in .NET

Tags: .net, rest, odata, basic-authentication, nav

As in the title I'm trying to call a specific REST API - let's call it **cursed_api** - exposed by 3rd-party NAV Server, and to access it I need to provide username and password.

First point: to access it via web browser, for testing purposes, I do need to use Internet Explorer, because with other browsers (eg. Chrome or Firefox) I always get the same error:
`{"error":{"code":"Authentication_InvalidCredentials","message":"The server has rejected the client credentials."}}`

But this is not the real problem. In Visual Studio solution I create an oData Connected Service, by the book. To download *$metadata* the only precaution is to add the authentication information (Authorization: Basic *base 64 credentials*) to the header.

Then I use the automatically generated code to try to call the **cursed_api** API, but I always get the same error message:
`{"error":{"code":"Authentication_InvalidCredentials","message":"The server has rejected the client credentials."}}`

I tried adding authentication policies in request header, in this way:

```
static void GetCursedApiList()
{
    string serviceRoot = String.Format("{0}/Company('{1}')", endpoint.TrimEnd('/'), company);

    NAV.NAV context = new NAV.NAV(new Uri(serviceRoot));
    context.SendingRequest2 += SendBaseAuthCredsOnTheRequest;

    IEnumerable<CursedApiObject> cursedApiObjects = context.CursedApiObject.Execute();
}

static void SendBaseAuthCredsOnTheRequest(object sender, SendingRequest2EventArgs e)
{
    string creds = String.Format(@"{0}\{1}:{2}", domain, username, password);
    creds = String.Format(@"{0}:{1}", username, password);
    string base64Creds = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(creds));

    e.RequestMessage.SetHeader("Authorization", String.Format("Basic {0}", base64Creds));
}
```

Then I tried using context credentials:

```
static void GetCursedApiList()
{
    string serviceRoot = String.Format("{0}/Company('{1}')", endpoint.TrimEnd('/'), company);

    NAV.NAV context = new NAV.NAV(new Uri(serviceRoot));
    context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);

    IEnumerable<CursedApiObject> cursedApiObjects = context.CursedApiObject.Execute();
}
```

But I had no luck.

Anyone who has faced the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simple, the 3rd-party vendor had given me invalid credentials (which, in fact, is the error message returned).

Comment: I am not sure how this answers the question

Comment: True. In fact, the most important question (at this point) still remains unresolved: why can I make the call with Internet Explorer, even with invalid credentials? At the moment I am unable to find an answer.